# Modify column to row for two columns in datatable and convert to JSON in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json

My Datatable looks like below.
Years   Category    msr 
2010    cake        872
2010     Soap       514
2011    Soap        5666
2011    cake        4391

When I convert to JSON I got not Problem.

```
[{"Years":"2010","Category":"cake","msr":872},
{"Years":"2010","Category":"Soap","msr":514},
{"Years":"2011","Category":"cake","msr":566},
{"Years":"2011","Category":"Soap","msr":615}]
```

but I want to convert the above datatable as below JSON.

```
[{"Years":"2010","cake":872}, {"Years":"2010","Soap":514}, {"Years":"2011","cake":566}, {"Years":"2011","Soap":615}]
```

My JSON Conversion Code:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> row;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
            }
            rows.Add(row);
        }
        return serializer.Serialize(rows);
```

Can some one help me with some code.

Comment: Show your JSON conversion code.

Comment: Hi, Added JSON Conversion Code.

Comment: `row.Add("Years", dr["Years"]); row.Add("cake", dr["msr"]);` ?

Comment: @DotNetDreamer - Only putting "cake" wont work. Sometimes the value is  "Soap".

Comment: @MattMurdock if its only these two then you can use condition or try this `row.Add(dr["Category"].ToString(), dr["msr"]);` ?

Comment: @MattMurdock check my answer below

Comment: @Jaswanth - Check DotNet Dreamer's answer and see how that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily. One thing to note that you don't need a loop inside a coloumn and secondly i have to initialize dictionary inside a loop so that i don't get `Dictionary contains already the same key` exception

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Years");
dt.Columns.Add("Category");
dt.Columns.Add("msr");

DataRow dtrow = dt.NewRow();
dtrow["Years"] = "2010";
dtrow["Category"] = "cake";
dtrow["msr"] = "872";
dt.Rows.Add(dtrow);

DataRow dtrow2 = dt.NewRow();
dtrow2["Years"] = "2010";
dtrow2["Category"] = "Soap";
dtrow2["msr"] = "514";
dt.Rows.Add(dtrow2);

List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
Dictionary<string, object> row;
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    row.Add("Years", dr["Years"]);
    row.Add(dr["Category"].ToString(), dr["msr"]);

    rows.Add(row);
}
```

i debugged this code and it gives the desire results. let me know for any updates

Comment: You beat me by 5 seconds. I was about to post an answer same as this. This works :)

Comment: @MattMurdock got some cake and soup that gave me a speed :D

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var result = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .Select(row => 
    { 
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>(); 
        dict.Add("Years", row[0]); 
        dict.Add(row[1].ToString(), row[2]); 
        return dict; 
    });
```

Where `dt` is your original data table.

Comment: Can u please help without linq. I am handling with older application where there is no support for linq?